# Print Or cancel it gives the same message and delettes the generated image

Tags: javascript, ajax, printing, html2canvas

In the below code which is working fine but only single issue i am facing is that the file which is generated by html2canvas is deleting on canceling the print which is correct but when i successfully saved the PDF file using Microsoft Print To PDF printer it successfully saves the file but it executes the deletes the file also why and how i do not know. Please help.

Either way the response is:

```
Response from server: 
success

Deleted generated image: 
success
```

and below is the rest of the code:

```
$("#myButtonS").click(function () {
    var staffno = "<?php echo $staffno; ?>";
    var container = $("#canvasSaveder");
    var charA = $("#charA");
    var horizontalPadding = (container.width() - charA.width()) / 2;
    var verticalMargin = (container.height() - charA.height()) / 2;

    charA.css({
        "color": "black !important",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "right": "0",
        "left": "0"
    });

    var userCancelledPrint = false; // Define the flag here

    html2canvas(container, {
        scale: 2,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
            $("#newimg").attr('src', imgsrc);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save_printed_id.php",
                data: {
                    imgBase64: dataURL,
                    staffid: staffno
                }
            }).done(function (o) {
                console.log('saved');
                printImage(imgsrc);
            });
        }
    });

    function printImage(imgSrc) {
        var staffno = "<?php echo $staffno; ?>";

        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=600');
        printWindow.document.open();
        printWindow.document.write('<html><body>');
        printWindow.document.write('<div class="pagerA">');
        printWindow.document.write('<img style="margin-top: -8px; margin-left: -8px;" src="' + imgSrc + '" width="105%" />');
        printWindow.document.write('</div>');
        printWindow.document.write('<div class="pagerA">');
        printWindow.document.write('<img src="../../../images/idBacks.jpg" width="100%" />');
        printWindow.document.write('</div>');
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();

        // Attach an event handler to the print window's beforeunload event
        printWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
            // Set the userCancelledPrint flag to true when the print window is closed
            userCancelledPrint = true;
        };

        printWindow.print();

        // Close the print window automatically after a delay (e.g., 5 seconds)
        setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.close();

            // Check if the user canceled the print job and delete the image if needed
            if (userCancelledPrint) {
                deleteGeneratedImage();
            }
        }, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed

        function deleteGeneratedImage() {
            // Implement code to delete the generated image here
            // For example, you can make an AJAX request to a PHP script that handles the deletion.
            // Ensure you have the necessary logic in place to identify and delete the correct image.
            // Replace the following with your actual delete logic:

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save_printed_id_cancelled.php",
                data: {
                    staffid: staffno
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                console.log('Response from server: ' + response);
                if (response.trim() === "success") {
                    console.log('Deleted generated image: ' + response);
                } else {
                    console.log('Failed to delete generated image: ' + response);
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

**save_printed_id_cancelled.php**

```
<?php
include ('inc/db.php');

$staffno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dba_si, $_POST['staffid']);
    $sqlIM13    = "select id, filename from id_photos
    where staffno = '$staffno'
    order by id desc
    ";
    $sqlIM14    = $dba_si->query($sqlIM13);
    $sqlIM15    = $sqlIM14->fetch_assoc();
    
    $fileItem5 = 'images/employees/empcards/'.$staffno.'/'.$sqlIM15['filename'];
    //echo $fileItem6 = 'images/employees/empcards/'.$staffno.'/'.$sqlIM15['filename']; // Echo before any deletions

if (unlink($fileItem5)){
    $dba_si->query("delete from id_photos where id = '".$sqlIM15['id']."' ");
    echo "success";
    // Log a message to a file
    error_log("Image deleted successfully for staffno: " . $staffno);
}else{
    echo "Failed to delete generated image: Error - " . error_get_last()['message'];
    // Log an error message to a file
    error_log("Failed to delete image for staffno: " . $staffno);
}

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing appears to be related to the sequence in which the generated file is being deleted. Based on your code implementation, it seems that the file is being deleted both when the user cancels the print operation and when the print window automatically closes after a 1-second delay.

Remove the call to deleteGeneratedImage() inside the printImage() function since the file should not be deleted in this case:

```
// Remove this part inside the printImage() function
setTimeout(function () {
    printWindow.close();

    // Check if the user cancelled the print job and delete the image if needed
    if (userCancelledPrint) {
        deleteGeneratedImage();
    }
}, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed
```

Inside the deleteGeneratedImage() function, add a check to determine whether the file should be deleted or kept. This check should be based on the userCancelledPrint variable. In the case of user cancellation, the file will be deleted:

```
function deleteGeneratedImage() {
    // Check if the user cancelled the print job
    if (userCancelledPrint) {
        // Implement the logic to delete the generated file here
        // For example, you can make an AJAX request to a PHP server to handle the deletion
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_printed_id_cancelled.php",
            data: {
                staffid: staffno
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log('Response from server: ' + response);
            if (response.trim() === "success") {
                console.log('Deleted generated image: ' + response);
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to delete generated image: ' + response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With these changes, the generated file will only be deleted if the user cancels the print operation. If the user successfully completes the print operation using "Microsoft Print To PDF," the generated file will not be deleted. Hope this can help you get it working

Comment: it is now not deleting and closing the window when i press on Cancel Button or directly close the window